# 2010 REST Delete List

Tags: 2010, list, rest, delete

I have a List that I have been tasked with creating. The idea is to make a "Master View" that joins several other lists from the same site into one. It is my understanding that it is no possible to do this directly, like one would in a SQL db. So my current idea is to download the lists to python with pandas, merge the lists on the lookup columns I put in them, and push the data to a new list. It's a bit wonky, but it should get the job done.

The issue here is that, after the joins, I've got nearly 18K records. I don't think added that many records will be a huge deal, as I have a pretty good function to setup batch posts to ListData.svc, but the Delete requests to ListData.svc seem to take forever for some reason; even after being batched 100 at a time. In the past, I've downloaded the data from both sources and used some sort of index to determine which rows should be updated, deleted, or added. There aren't many good ways I could go about making an index with this particular dataset.

So my idea now is to delete the list itself and recreate it with a template. The only issue is that I can't seem to find a way to do this with the 2010 REST services. I tried sending a Delete request to `<site url>/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/<list name>` but got a `405 Method Not Allowed` in response. Even if I got that to work, I don't know how to create a new list from a template with that service.

### Questions

1. Is it even possible to delete a whole list from the 2010 REST API (without JS) and if so how?
2. How does one go about creating a list from a template with the same API?

Answer (score 0):

Did you send the request as a POST or DELETE, not just a GET?

For 2013 REST API I had to send a delete request as a POST with "DELETE" in the header:

```
url: http://site url/_api/web/lists(guid'list GUID')​
method: POST​
Headers: ​
    X-RequestDigest: form digest value​
    IF-MATCH: etag or "*"​
    X-HTTP-Method: DELETE
```

Comment: It was initially a DELETE request. I just tried it again as a POST with a DELETE header as you have here and I got the same `405` error.